# Windows CE Hive Registy flushing of subkey

Tags: registry, windows-ce

I'm developing using a WinCE 5 device.

I'm saving changes to the hive based registry, which is on a persistent medium.  My keys are under HKLM\Softare\AppName.   HKLM\RegPersisted = 1 for reference.

I find that even though I call Flush() on my subkey (from Compact Framework), the change is not persisted if I turn off immediately after.

Similarly, if I call

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.Flush();
```

I get the same result.

However, if I call

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "RegFlushKey", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint RegFlushKey(uint hKey);
```

with the uint for the HKLM, then the change does persist if I turn off immediately after.

Any ideas what the regular .Net versions aren't working?  Or perhaps they are working, but for some reason it's a lazy flush, whereas the coredll direct version is not lazy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using Reflector on mscoree (located at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\Debugger\BCL`) for the Compact Framework shows that a call to RegistryKey.Flush simply ends up here:

```
[DllImport("mscoree", EntryPoint="#481")]
public static extern int FlushKey(IntPtr hRootKey);
```

At this point it goes into compiled native code so we can't trace it any further.  One would think that mscoree would simply call RegFlushKey for you, but your tests (I've not verified the results) indicate that it's doing something else.  The only workaround that I can think of would be to manually flush via P/Invoke.

Are you *certain* that the managed-only code *never* saves the changes but the p/invoke version *always* does?

Comment: Thanks for that ctacke.  I'm not 100% certain no (and unfortunately can't repeat my experiments until pressure is off from this deadline), but what I did was:  a) set value, flush key (.net), reboot, check key.  Was incorrect value.  a) set value, flush HKLM  (.net), reboot, check key.  Was incorrect value.  c) set value, flush via p/invoke, reboot, check key. Was definitely correct value.  Only did one iteration of this as I say, but it was enough to demonstrate that a) and b) certainly didn't work at *least* "sometimes".